# Which datetime picker for Angular2?

Tags: angular, datetimepicker

I am developing a website with angular 2 and in a form, I would like to use a datetime picker.

Unfortunatly, I only saw on google components which use other libraries like bootstrap or jquery.

Is there a light datetime picker which use only angular 2?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

We're using  "mydatepicker": "^1.9.7" in our Angular 2 app. And it works really well, without a lot of extra boilerplate or dependencies.

Comment: Can I pick a time with this component ?

Comment: @Charlyberthet did you findout any good datetime picker?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for really tiny datepicker you should take a look at

> [ngx-mydatepicker](https://github.com/kekeh/ngx-mydatepicker)

It's really light and supported by any browser.

Comment: Can I pick a time with this component ?

Comment: Unfortunately nope